# Storing variables to decrease calculations in mediawiki templates

Tags: mediawiki-templates

Since I started editing `Wikicode` templates I've felt the need to store calculated values to decrease load times for templates. Typically I work around the problem by calculating the same thing multiple times in the same template, but it won't cut it this time I think.

I'm working on a table that shows;

- The best buy price for an item, calculating both prices (one of the prices is straight from a database, hence less calculations, but the other price is calculated through a switchcase for databse values) and taking the best value (which means the template will always have three calculations; two for the comparison and one for the final result that is being displayed).
- The best sell price for an item, calculating two prices for comparison and calculating two more prices to check the best price out of three (`if statement; A>B?[A>C?A:C]:[B>C?B:C]` ), making for at least five calculations.
- The difference between these two values. I have no idea how to make this and I feel like it is gonna be a HUGE if-statement, with at least `3 * 5 = 15` calculations, if I'm gonna do the same thing as I usually do.

I hope you can see that having 23 calculations for 3 cells in a table is a bit too much, especially because the table is supposed to hold about a hundred items, and will need quite a bit more switch cases and database calls for several values.

*So*, is there a way to store calculations in a variable in `Wikicode`? And if not, how should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way of storing a variable in a plain `Wikicode` template. Instead I would recommend that you install the [Scribuntu](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto) extention which allows you to use [Lua scripting](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Lua_scripting) which you can invoke from inside your templates.

Comment: It might be worth noting that this is how the problem is solved on Wikipedia.